# Preference Headers not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, preference

I am trying to rewrite my `PreferenceActivity` to use `Preference-Headers` I followed the official docs but My Headers are not showing for some reason. I just get a blank screen.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <header
                android:fragment="com.mikebdev.refuel.SettingsActivity$DesignFragment"
                android:title="@string/pref_header_design"
                android:summary="@string/pref_header_design_summary"
                />
        <header
                android:fragment="com.mikebdev.refuel.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment"
                android:title="@string/pref_header_units"
                android:summary="@string/pref_header_units_summary"/>
        <header
                android:fragment="com.mikebdev.refuel.SettingsActivity$DatabaseFragment"
                android:title="@string/pref_header_db"
                android:summary="@string/pref_header_db_summary"/>
    </preference-headers>
</preference-headers>
```

And heres My SettingsActivity:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "RFPref";
    public static PreferenceManager prefMgr;



    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }
}
```

I am going to leave out the inner PreferenceFragment classes..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have redundant `<preference-headers>` elements. Get rid of the inner one.

Comment: Thats what I call a major copy paste fail ... -.-' I'm off today. Thanks so much. will mark your answer as accepted in 5 min. :)

Comment: @mike.b93: I filed a tools feature request for Lint to yelp about this sort of problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56573